# HTTP method for files using python

Tags: python, http, post

I have a website that has a form which accepts two input type="file". I would like to do these POST requests using python. How can I do that?

Comment: well, I wonder if you can do a post request on a website using python?

Comment: I can do POST using python with the httplib library. My question is not related to the language whatsoever. My question is: in the case of an input of type file, should I pass the contents of the file or the path of the file in the POST request parameters

Comment: Yes, you have to pass the contents of the file. What good would the path do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some Python code to POST to a website, then use either the included `httplib` web client or the 3rd party `httplib2` web client. You could also consider using `curl` to do this.

In the POST transaction, you would typically send all the form fields including the file name as parameters, and then send bulk data like file contents in the body of the request.

On the other hand, if you want your Python code to display a form and accept POST requests, then use a simple framework like `bottle` which makes it easy to write RESTful web servers in Python. http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/   See this URL for an example of how a web server would implement file uploads: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-data

Comment: thx for your answer. I think I was unclear with my question. My question is: in the case of an input of type file, should I pass the contents of the file or the path of the file in the POST request parameters. I am using the httplib